# Move a button from one UITableViewCell to another with animation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, animation

I have a button and I want to keep track of which cell has the button with firebase.  I can do this by putting the button in all cells and just make it visible in the one cell using firebase data.  The part I'm stuck on is animating the button to move from one cell to another.

The only way I can think of is to put a delay on moving it from one to another, then have a separate animation happen. Then I think if I make the delay the same as the animation's duration then it will look like it just moved.  I just thought of that while typing this but let me know if there's an easier/better way please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty tough thing to do, and animations can sometimes be one of the most difficult parts of mobile development. You aren't super clear on what your animation should look like, but since `UITableViewCell`s each have their own `contentView`s I don't think directly animating the button from one cell to another is possible.

The best method I could think is to:

1) Draw a button on the screen at the location of the button you want to move

2) Hide the real button underneath

3) Animate this fake button over the tableview to the spot of the new, real button

4) End the animation and show the real button.

But you might have to block user interaction with the tableview while this happens to prevent them from scrolling and screwing up the animation...

Comment: Yeah that's the only way I can think of doing it.  The animation is just to move it. No resizing or changing in any way, just moving it down.  Might have a bounce at the end if I can get away with it lol

Comment: Im going to have to agree with Zolnoor on this one. I dont think moving the actual button from one cell to the other is possible.

Comment: Okay i'll just select as correct.  I mean it's pretty much the same thing I said but it is the correct answer and you actually were more specific about it than the way I mentioned.  So i'll mark this and I guess we'll see if someone can find a better way but yeah I doubt there is one.

Comment: Unless there is some way to actually take a button out of the table, move it to a location, then re-insert into the table or something